# Missing Farm Configuration Wizard

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am installing SharePoint 2010 single farm on my 64bit Win7 Ultimate development machine.  After a lot of pain and apparent success of the installation, I am not finding the "Farm Configuration Wizard" on the "Configuration Wizards" page of Central Administration.

Looking for reasons why and things to check to make it show up.

Thanks

Comment: This kind of question should be asked on superuser.com.

Comment: I have no idea why you would suggest this. Please explain

Answer (score 3):

Standalone installations of SharePoint do not support farm configuration wizard.

You get this message when trying the address of the farm config wizard directly:
http://server:prt/_admin/adminconfigintro.aspx?scenarioid=adminconfig&welcomestringid=farmconfigurationwizard_welcome